# How to use firebase functions to return the json content of a file saved in firebase storage

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I want to frequently update client side indexeddb data store from the cloud.
So what I am thinking is to call the firebase function and have the function fetch an update json file in firebase storage and then return the content of that json file to client side which will update the indexeddb afterwards.

I tried to return this [json file](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/konstant-ccbcc.appspot.com/o/storeid.json?alt=media&token=8d56ba73-331e-452e-b0d4-e552264feee3)with this code

```
exports.updateProductCatalogue = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const filepath = data.filepath
    const bucketname = data.bucket

     
    const bucket = storage.bucket();
    const remoteFile = bucket.file("storeid.json");

    let buffer = '';
    remoteFile.createReadStream()
    .on('error', function(err) {console.log(err)})
    .on('data', function(response) {
        buffer += response
    })
    .on('end', function() {
        //console.log(buffer);
        return buffer
     
    })
  })
```

when ever I try to deploy the code to the cloud it throws this error

```
firebase-functions/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/node_modules/p-limit/index.js:30
    } catch {}
            ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

I was able to narrow the source of the error to this code

```
 const bucket = storage.bucket();
```

How can I return the json content on the file via firebase functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an issue with your code (phew!) but a configuration of your project. [Try using node 10+ to address the exception syntax error](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/1223). After you update node+npm, don't forget to update you `package.json`:

```json
{
"...": "...",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10",
    "npm": "6"
  }
}
```

Comment: I checked my package.json and I'm "node": "10"

Comment: What about your currently installed versions? In a terminal, try `node -v & npm -v`.

Comment: v8.13.0(node) and 6.4.1 (npm)

Comment: You need to update your node version to 10+, try `nvm install-latest-npm`, if you haven't installed nvm, I highly encourage you to do so =)